# How to get nested data from eager loading on Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have Post and User model with relationship as below.

```
User Model:
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
Post Model:
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

And below is Api function that called from Ajax.

```
public function Api(Request $request){
    $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

I can render user's name and user's email from relation into table as below.

```
    loadData().then(data => {
        let  html = ``;
        data.forEach((post,index) => 
            html += `<tr >                                        
                <td> ${post.title} </td>                                            
                <td> ${post.user['name']}</td> 
                <td> ${post.user['email']}</td> 
                <td> *num_of_post*</td> //<--need num of post here
            </tr>`
            )
        $("#table_wrapper").html(html);
    })
```

Also I would like to render the *number of post* for each user. I try `${post.user.posts.lenght}` but command not work. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
```

you can use:

```
$posts = Post::with(['user' => function($q) {
    $q->withCount('posts');  
}])->get();
```

and later you can use it like so:

```
<td>${post.user['posts_count']}</td>
```

Comment: Dear Marcin Nabiałek, Work great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @joenpcnpcsolution Glad I was able to help